# Math.random in for loop

Tags: jquery

i'm using Math.random to choose a random position for the alien, but when i use it in a function inside a loop it doesn't give a different position.so what exactly is happening in here?

```
  for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
     createAliens( parseInt(Math.random() * 940 + 1));}

    var alien;
    //creating aliens
   function createAliens(x) {
      $('body').append('<img class="alien" src="alien.ico" width="70" height="70">');
      alien=$('.alien');
      alien.css({
         position: "absolute",
         left: x,
         top:-20
         });
    setInterval(function () {
        alien.css({
        top: "+=10"
         });
        if (alien.position().top > 450) {
        alien.remove();
        }
    }, 1000)
  }
```

Comment: You are setting **all** objects with a `.alien` class to the same position each time the `createAliens` function is called.

Comment: also, `+=10` doesn't look like a valid css value to me.  might want to check on that.

Comment: +=10 is actually a valid value and it means top: alien.position().top+10 @SamAxe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting all aliens with the same position using alien.css; you need to loop over alien to set initial css position like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //create aliens 
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 $('body').append('<img class="alien" src="alien.ico" width="70" height="70">');
  }

  //reference here all aliens
    var alien = $('.alien');
  //set initial value, each alien itself
  $.each(alien, function() {
    $(this).css({
         position: "absolute",
         left: parseInt(Math.random() * 940 + 1) + 'px',
         top: -20
    });
  });

  //coming down
  setInterval(function() {
        alien.css({
            top: "+=10"
        });
        if (alien.position().top > 450) {
            alien.remove();
        }
  }, 1000);
});
```